# How To implementing multi layer frame or widget in Qt?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

How can I implement this in Qt, I am using PyQt and Qt Designer but confusing how to use layering like in the following image.

[image]

- I want to first layer in index 0 to show the image or video,
- then the second layer in index 2 is media control which can hide when no move from mouse,
- and layer 3 in index 3 when change the volume in example
- layer 4 in index 4 for notification etc.

is possible to do this in Qt?

Comment: When I worked on qt4/c++ I usually setLayout on a widget (Qlabel being the usual container) then set the children widget (e.g. button) onto this layout. Not sure how this is done in qt5 and qml...

Comment: @Scheff for this kind of interface, overriding the paintEvent alone won't be effective: at least layer 2 and 3 require mouse interaction (with the third possibly being able to be moved around the interface), and making all the computation required for all object geometries might result in decreased performance. Using "floating" child widgets without any layout is a better solution.

Comment: @musicamante I agree. I didn't think of that the effect can be achieved simpler by stacking widgets onto each other with a resp. `QLayout` (like recommended by @user3528438).

Comment: If layer1 is a video then this could prove difficult.  Video rendering in `Qt` is generally handed off to 3rd party libraries such as `gstreamer`.  As such, `Qt` is not in control of the rendering of the video and can not, therefore, act as a compositor for the various layers.

Comment: @G.M. that can be solved using QGraphicsVideoItem and using a QGraphicsView instead of QVideoWidget.

Comment: @musicamante Indeed.  I'd completely forgotten about `QGraphicsVideoItem`.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the very few cases for which using a layout is *not* suggested, as the visible widgets are "floating" and should be possibly moved around.

The solution is to create a "container" widget that has all those controls as *children*.

Then, some widgets will need some repositioning and resizing (for instance, the control bar should always be on bottom and occupy the whole width), and that can be implemented in the `resizeEvent()`.

[image: Screenshot of the code below]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ControlBar(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)
        buttons = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(buttons)
        buttons.addWidget(QtWidgets.QToolButton(text='play'))
        buttons.addWidget(QtWidgets.QToolButton(text='stop'))
        buttons.addStretch()


class VolumeWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(1)
        handle = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        handle.setFixedHeight(12)
        handle.setStyleSheet('''
            QFrame {
                border: 1px solid darkGray;
                border-radius: 2px;
                background: #aa646464;
            }
        ''')
        layout.addWidget(handle)
        volumeLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(volumeLayout)
        for i in range(4):
            volumeLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Vertical))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.startPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            delta = event.pos() - self.startPos
            self.move(self.pos() + delta)


class Notification(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Notification', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)


class PlayerWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.video = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.video.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('movie.png'))
        self.video.setScaledContents(True)
        self.controlBar = ControlBar(self)
        self.notification = Notification(self)
        self.volumeWidget = VolumeWidget(self)
        self.volumeWidget.move(30, 30)

        self.setStyleSheet('''
            VolumeWidget, ControlBar {
                border: 1px outset darkGray;
                border-radius: 4px;
                background: #aad3d3d3;
            }
            VolumeWidget:hover, ControlBar:hover {
                background: #d3d3d3;
            }
            Notification {
                border: 1px outset darkGray;
                border-radius: 4px;
                background: #aa242424;
            }
            Notification QLabel {
                color: white;
            }
        ''')

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self.video.pixmap() and not self.video.pixmap().isNull():
            return self.video.pixmap().size()
        return QtCore.QSize(640, 480)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # set the geometry of the "video"
        videoRect = QtCore.QRect(
            QtCore.QPoint(), 
            self.video.sizeHint().scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        videoRect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
        self.video.setGeometry(videoRect)

        # control panel
        controlHeight = self.controlBar.sizeHint().height()
        controlRect = QtCore.QRect(0, self.height() - controlHeight, 
            self.width(), controlHeight)
        self.controlBar.setGeometry(controlRect)

        # notification
        notificationWidth = max(self.notification.sizeHint().width(), self.width() * .6)
        notificationRect = QtCore.QRect(
            (self.width() - notificationWidth) * .5, 20, 
            notificationWidth, self.notification.sizeHint().height()
        )
        self.notification.setGeometry(notificationRect)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QtCore.Qt.black)
```

Note that in this simple case I only used an image. If you want to play video, you should use the Qt Multimedia module, and in order to correctly have transparency of controls a QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsVideoItem must be used.
In this case, PlayerWidget can directly be a subclass of QGraphicsView.

Comment: that mean the video or image place in Qwidget (PlayerWidgets) ? not need create a frame in the first layer, then create other frame to second layer for video control ?

Comment: if in web with html and css we can create one layer with div and fill the content then create other div and change the index in css to make layer 1 and others layers  to be stacked up with many layers. can we implement that consep in Qt ?

Comment: @blanksix sorry but I can't understand your first comment, can you try to explain yourself better? About the second comment, conceptually it's exactly what I've done. Have you tried my code? Have you read the documentation of its classes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to implement "layers" - you can add child widgets without any layout and resize/move them on resize event of host widget (using event filter). First layer can be organized with any layout as usual.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Layer(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, host, child, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft, setWidth = False, setHeight = False, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._host = host
        self._child = child
        self._alignment = alignment
        self._setWidth = setWidth
        self._setHeight = setHeight
        child.setParent(host)
        host.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if watched != self._host or event.type() != QtCore.QEvent.Resize:
            return False
        hostSize = event.size()
        childSize = self._child.sizeHint()
        alignment = self._alignment
        x = 0
        y = 0
        dWidth = max(0, hostSize.width() - childSize.width())
        dHeight = max(0, hostSize.height() - childSize.height())
        if alignment & Qt.AlignRight:
            x = dWidth
        elif alignment & Qt.AlignHCenter:
            x = dWidth / 2
        if alignment & Qt.AlignVCenter:
            y = dHeight / 2
        elif alignment & Qt.AlignBottom:
            y = dHeight
        width = hostSize.width() if self._setWidth else childSize.width()
        height = hostSize.height() if self._setHeight else childSize.height()
        self._child.setGeometry(x, y, width, height)
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("right label")
    label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("bottom label")
    layer1 = Layer(widget, label1, Qt.AlignRight)
    layer2 = Layer(widget, label2, Qt.AlignBottom | Qt.AlignHCenter, True)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```